# CakePHP 1.26: Bug in 'Security' component?

Tags: security, cakephp, components, cakephp-1.2

For those of you who may have read this earlier, I've done a little research and completely revamped my question. I've been having a problem where my form requests get blackholed by the Security component, although everything works fine when the Security component is disabled. I've traced it down to a single line in a form:

```
<?php echo $form->create('Audition');?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php __('Edit Audition');?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $form->input('ensemble');
        echo $form->input('position');
        echo $form->input('aud_date');
        // The following line works fine...
       echo $form->input('owner');  
       // ...but the following line blackholes when Security included
        // and the form is submitted:
        // echo $form->input('owner', array('disabled'=>'disabled');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $form->end('Submit');?>
```

(I've commented out the offending line for clarity) I think I'm following the rules by using the form helper; as far as I can tell, this is a bug in the Security component, but I'm too much of a CakePHP n00b to know for sure. I'd love to get some feedback, and if it's a real bug, I'll submit it to the CakePHP team. I'd also love to know if I'm just being dumb and missing something obvious here.

(sorry to address comments here, but I didn't have enough space for them in comments)

**UPDATE**: Thanks Jesh, you're 100% right about that -- "an input value will not be submitted when it is disabled". I even looked it up on [the official HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1), where it says, "[A disabled element] cannot receive user input nor will its value be submitted with the form". But Cake *IS* submitting the value with the form! When I disable using the Security Component, I can look at the POST data being submitted with the form, and sure enough, the 'owner' field has been submitted! Unfortunately, this is precisely the behavior I wanted, but it seems to be in disagreement with the official HTML spec...so I'm thinking that this is a bug with the standard form helper. I'll report this to the CakePHP team as a bug, but I'd love to hear from anyone who can confirm or refute this.

Also, Jesh, your idea to use the secure key and set it to false works great, but I really don't WANT to leave this field unsecured (in fact, I PARTICULARLY don't want to leave this field unsecured), and it seems to me that I shouldn't have to. In fact, now I'm thinking that this could ALSO be a bug in the Security component; I'm *using* the FormHelper to create my forms here -- so shouldn't the Security component be able to handle this??

@Miles: your solution works great too -- thanks! But it still leaves open the same questions I raised above.

Answer (score 1):

Well, an input value will not be submitted when it is disabled. But since you output the field using Cakephp's FormHelper, SecurityComponent expect the input value must be listed in `Controller->data` array otherwise it blackhole your request.

Try adding `secure` key in form options array and set it to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Add this into your beforeFilter():

$this->Security->disabledFields = array('owner');

Answer (score 0):

You can use `readonly` instead of `disabled` in the form. That works for me. `Disabled` is black-holed intentionally.